# MS Access 2007: Add AUTOINCREMENT field from MAKE TABLE query

Tags: database, ms-access

I am creating a table T2, from an existing table T1, using the MAKE TABLE query type and need to add an autoincrementing field as a primary key to the new table T2.

I'm curious of the SQL required. For example:

```
SELECT AUTOINCREMENT(1, 1) AS ID, T1.*, INTO T2 FROM T1
```

The `AUTOINCREMENT(1, 1) AS ID` comment of course does not work but that is what I suspected might work and am using for illustrative purposes only to show what I am trying to do.

Note that I cannot alter the table after it is created using the ALTER TABLE statement, I need to build the AUTOINCREMENT field (and populate it) on the fly when T2 is created from T1.

Comment: Why can you not use alter table?

Comment: The query runs when the DB is opened as a form opens for user input. I suppose I could build a macro to run the MAKE TABLE query then another ALTER TABLE query if I need to.

Comment: I reckon you will have to. You can run code in various for events, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment you said "query runs when the DB is opened as a form opens for user input. I suppose I could build a macro to run the MAKE TABLE query then another ALTER TABLE query if I need to".

Instead of recreating T2 every time, it could be simpler to create T2 once, then empty out its contents each time before appending from T1.  To discard the rows from T2:

```
Dim strSql as String
strSql = "DELETE FROM T2;"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

If you want to reset the autonumber to 1 for the ID column, you can use an ALTER TABLE statement.

```
strSql = "ALTER TABLE T2 ALTER COLUMN ID COUNTER(1, 1);"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

Then add the contents of T1 to T2.

```
strSql = "INSERT INTO T2 (field1, field2)" & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT field1, field2 FROM T1;"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

Just leave the ID column out of the field lists and let the autonumbering deal with it.  You can control the order in which the T1 rows are added with an ORDER BY in the SELECT part of that statement if you wish.

I used ADO (CurrentProject.Connection) to execute all three of those statements.  However the first and third statements should run just fine under DAO if you prefer.  But that ALTER TABLE statement must be run from ADO.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply like that ....

```
Select Name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM Person pp 
     WHERE pp.ID<=Person.ID) AS serialNo
FROM Person
```